# DarkMode :- Color inverting not working for WKWebview Tableview Content

Tags: ios, css, webview, wkwebview, ios-darkmode

.css File

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
 :root {
        color-scheme: light dark;
    filter: invert(100%);
   -webkit-filter: invert(100%)
 }
}
```

This how it looks in WKWebView

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the table tag, table data color inverted properly

```
 @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
     // root tag inverting all the components color except the table.
     : root {
            color-scheme: light dark;
        filter: invert(100%);
       -webkit-filter: invert(100%)
     }
    //table tag needed for inverting table content.
    table {
            filter: invert(100%);
     }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please help me on this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830561/wkwebview-dark-and-light-mode-with-dynamic-url-in-swift-5